# What does it mean by "drank my bodyweight"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In English Action/Thriller movie "xXx: Return of Xander Cage", *Serena* asked by Xander about the tatoo on her body.

> Xander: What about that sexy one?
>
> Serena: This? Phoenix out of the ashes. Eighteen hours in a chair in
>   Mexico. I **drank my bodyweight** in tequila to get through it.

*[Phoenix out of the ashes](https://www.google.com/search?q=Phoenix%20out%20of%20the%20ashes&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRvsyjjtbTAhWkxYMKHSXYA0IQsAQINw)* is design of tatoo, But what does it mean by "drank my bodyweight"?

Comment: If the person weighs 60 kilos, this expression implies they drank 60 kilos of tequila (although, as the answer says, it's not meant to be taken literally – it's hyperbole.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There phrase "drank my body weight" is simply to emphasize the amount of tequila that the character Selene had drank when she was in Mexico. It isn't intended to be taken literally, and is more just a figure of speech that implies that one has drunk a lot. Thus, making the phrase more relatable to the person watching the movie, as they will have a better understanding of the sheer amount of tequila that was consumed.